# Looping a powershell script

Tags: sql, powershell

This might seem like an easy question but I had to ask. I have a powershell script that calls another script and it patches a SQL database. Normally you can just patch all databases at once, but sometimes that halts and you have to cancel it and do single datasbases instead. Here is the script I made to do this `sqlps` is already run prior to this code segment:

```
do {
    $dabname = Read-Host "Enter the database name or (stop) to end"
    if($dabname -ne "stop") {
    $sclient = Read-Host "Enter Client name"
        $date = Get-Date -Format "yymmdd"
        $sqlsrvname = Read-Host "Please enter the sql server name"
        SQL-remote -DBServer $sqlsrvname -DBNameList $dabname –client $sclient –mainline HTFS –datefolder $date –targetenv $sqlsrvname}
    }until($dabname -eq "stop")
```

but it keeps telling me the server doesnt exist, I cant figure out what I did wrong can someone please tell me whats missing? This script its suppose to; once working; keep asking if you want to patch more databases after patching them until you say "stop." The `sql-remote` is a function in which the sql patch script is stored.

Comment: I presume the SQL server doesn't have an instance that would also have to be defined? Can you wrap a `if(Test-Connection $sqlsrvname -Count 1 -Quiet){SQL-Remote ...stuff here} Else { Write-Error -message "Failed to Ping Host: $sqlsrvname" }`

Comment: yeah i have a separate section like this one but that includes an instance, this one doesn't because not all environments have one. ill try that but i feel like there is something wrong with my code since the server isnt connecting? i use similar codes for the normal non-do loop sections of my script and they work fine.

Comment: Can you post the error message its kicking back? is `SQL-Remote` a custom function you have? does it have any -verbose or -debug output you can flag for?

Comment: ill try it and get back to you. thanks!